# Success message not displayed in Django ClassBasedView

Tags: python, django, message, django-class-based-views, django-messages

I am trying to display success message after saving form. I am using [message framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/messages/#adding-messages-in-class-based-views) for this

**settings.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [TEMPLATE_PATH],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

**views.py**

```
class VolunteerCreateView(SuccessMessageMixin, CreateView):
    model = Volunteer
    form_class = VolunteerForm
    template_name = 'volunteer.html'
    success_message = 'Thank you!'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('volunteer')
```

**volunteer.html**

```
{% if messages %}
    <div class="alert center block" role="alert">
        <ul class="messages">
            {% for message in messages %}
            <li class="text-center"{% if message.tags %} class="{{ message.tags }}"{% endif %}>{{ message }}</li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    </div>
{% endif %}.....
```

But the message is not displayed. I can see the message json on request header in redirected url but is not displayed. 
Part of request header

```
Cookie:olfsk=olfsk1757071755791586; hblid=HecPjm2lDQ2xTzgn3m39N0J00JEB6o1A; sessionid=z8zh4t13mw655mf3yn1vfnow8y58zxt9; csrftoken=GZxsdPZmBsefPU0nv7ZEfEaxsnPCMjIehpiFihY3GtTrhFnuFc5c3NXplD35Qslw; ext_name=jaehkpjddfdgiiefcnhahapilbejohhj;  
 messages="ab8f5c6976dd0939d4f1b867ca564577ba9cc0d7$[[\"__json_message\"\0540\05425\054\"Thank you!\"]]"
```

What could be the  reason that message is not displayed. Is there anything I am missing.

Comment: have you import this line `from django.contrib.messages.views import SuccessMessageMixin` in your **views.py**

Comment: @Akash I have added the import line